# Time taken to resolve DNS

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, internal-dns

I need to find out the time it takes to resolve DNS for a specific website.

For example: I need to find out in how many milliseconds it takes to resolve abc.com using the 8.8.8.8 global DNS server and using the local DNS server.

Can I get this information using the `nslookup` command? I tried this but it doesn't show the time taken.

Domain Controller: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Client OS: Windows 7 Professional

[image: nslookup screenshot]

Comment: "nslookup -debug abc.com" ?

Comment: I just tried this on windows 8.1 and don't see any durations, but plenty of TTLs.

Comment: Run a packet capture on the client, filter for DNS, run your queries with nslookup, check the response times in the packet capture.

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not appear to natively provide the tools to do this. You will have to install a third party 'Windows DNS response time' monitoring tool.